# Definition of smooth curves in Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis - why nonzero derivative?

Tags: complex-analysis, terminology, definition, curves

> A **parametrized curve** is a function $z(t)$ which maps a closed interval $[a, b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ to the complex plane. We shall impose regularity conditions on the parametrization which are always verified in the situations that occur in this book. We say that the parametrized curve is **smooth** if $z'(t)$ exists and is continuous on $[a, b]$, and $z'(t) \neq 0$ for $t \in[a, b]$.

Above is the definition of smooth parameterized curves given in Stein and Shakarchi's *[Complex Analysis](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691113852/complex-analysis)*.

**Questions**:

(i) Why do we require $z'(t) \not= 0$? I have not seen this condition used in any proofs.

(ii) Where is the "regularity condition" imposed - I thought this meant $z(t) \in C^{\infty}[a,b]$ (?)

Comment: Requiring $z'(t)\neq 0$ means that the _image_ of the curve has to look nice as well. If you allow $z'(t) = 0$ at places, then you can make curves whose parametrisations are nice and differentiable, but whose image has creases and cusps. For instance, the curve $t^2+it^3$ for $t\in [-1, 1]$. They probably want to avoid that.

Comment: If $z'(t)$ is allowed to be zero, the curve could trace out a path that contains a sharp cusp, despite $z$ being perfectly smooth. The trick is that $z$ has zero velocity at the sharp point so there is no abrupt change in direction. Often books show a few examples like this to explain why they impose such regularity conditions.

Comment: There are at least two reasons: on the one hand, this implies that the geometry of the curve itself (parametrization aside) is "nice". In particular, it implies that one or both of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{dx}{dy}$ exist at each point. On the other hand, it also implies that you haven't chosen a "misleading" parametrization that spends a disproportionate amount of time at one point. If you admit such parametrizations then line integrals depend on the parametrization, which is very bad.

Comment: @Ian Can you elaborate on what goes wrong if line integrals depend on the parametrization?

Comment: @littleO In the abstract, it's just nice for line integrals to only depend on the image and orientation, not the parametrization. In the context of calculating real integrals using the residue theorem, these "misleading parametrizations" are just useless in that they give you the wrong answer.

Comment: @Ian I'm proving that the definition of the line integrals doesn't depend on the the parametrization, but I can't see where I'm using the fact that the derivative of the curve is never 0. Do you have an example of two parametrizations of the same curve such that the line integrals give different values?

Comment: Just to add my 50 cents here: imagine a map $t \mapsto (1, 1)$ for $t \in [0, 1]$. It would be considered as "smooth" if you allow $z'(t)=0$.

Comment: @JKEG consider the case when $f(t)$ hangs at some point while your parameter goes through some $(a, b)$